# R session returning particular error when attempting to work with an API response

Tags: r, api, httr, jsonlite

I am trying to work with the "httr" and "jsonlite" packages for the first time to work with APIs in R.
I have attempted to run the following commands to access the data I need from the appropriate source.

```
res <- GET("https://www.gov.uk/contracts-finder")
data <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
```

However, when running the second command I am confronted with the following error message.

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <!--[if lt IE 9
                     (right here) ------^
```

Would be grateful for any pointers as to what is going wrong here!

Comment: That is a "normal HTML page", not JSON (the `<!DOCTYPE>` is a clear indicator of that).

Comment: What is the approach to convert the data then? What command should I replace fromJSON() with

Comment: j_abrams The URI https://www.gov.uk/contracts-finder leads to an htm file, not to a json. In fact it leads to the front page of a search engine. The jsons you are looking for are likely to came after you do some search (i.e send some input to the search engine).
If you want to capture the HTML content from gov.uk/contracts-finder, try rvest::read_html().

Comment: j_abrams, APIs that return *actual data* (and not HTML for a UI) tend to have clear http endpoints, such as `host.com/api/v1/get_contract_info`. You cannot just point `GET` to a regular website and expect that either (a) `GET` will know how to find underlying data, or (b) the web server will infer that you are trying to scrape their data and give a different response. Additionally, data-retrieving APIs are not guaranteed, sometimes not-written because (a) just not done, or (b) many websites prohibit scraping.

Comment: In this case, though, a quick google for [`site:gov.uk "contracts" "finder" "api"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agov.uk+"contracts"+"finder"+"api") (quotes are very useful there) returns https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/apidocumentation/, which gives good instructions on what you need to do to be able to programmatically pull data.

Answer (score 0):

The Contracts finder page is https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/Search

Don't know how to get a json response, but if you fill the form, the browser sends à POST request as this one :

POST https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/Search

The body of the request is (for the search word 'house') :

```
keywords=house&location=all_locations&regions%5B%5D=&postcode=&postcode_distance_select=5+miles&postcode_distance=5&speculative=1&planning=1&tender=1&form_token=kM26gd5FjxoNm5C7WASTeiI6IC1aPCI9&adv_search=
```

You should try to forge the request with package httr to get an HTML content and parse the response with rvest or xml.